# Getting class instantiation to work in Java

Tags: java, instantiation

So I'm very new to programming and just trying to instantiate a class in another class, but i keep getting an error that says: `Cannot Resolve Symbol`. Could someone tell me which area the problem lies in?

My First Class looks like this:

```
public class Triangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }
    public static void Draw (int num)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

The second looks like this:

```
public class Lab01
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
           Triangle obj2 = new Triangle.Draw(5);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are these classes in different packages? you need add `import` statement in `Lab01` if they are.

Comment: show the actual stacktrace....

Comment: why you want instantiate since it is static method?

Comment: new Triangle(), instantiation of an object is a method called the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're at least 2 issues:

1. The first is that a program must have only *one* `main` function. Yours here has two. The `main` function in your `Triangle` class should be removed.
2. The other issue is that, to actually *instantiate* a class, you need to invoke the class' constructor with the `new` operator, but your `Triangle obj2 = new Triangle.Draw(5);` line does not do this. Instead, it tries to use a `static void` method, which does not instantiate or return anything.

You should consider changing your `Triangle` as follows:

```
public class Triangle
{
    public Triangle() {
        System.out.println("Constructing triangle instance");
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing triangle instance");
    }
}

// using the class
Triangle t = new Triangle();
t.draw();
```

This gives you a public default constructor and also a non-static `draw` method that should take care of drawing the specific instance you've created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your Triangle object

```
//remove the static modifier if using below
Triangle obj2 = new Triangle();
obj2.draw(5);


//since your method is static you can just call it from the class also.
Triangle.draw(5);
```

What you were doing was trying to assign the return value from `Triangle.draw()` to your Triangle object. Since draw is `void` and does not return a Triangle type, it throws the error.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods) is a good stackoverflow post that shows a great example of when to use `static` methods.

Comment: Trying to access static methods from instances is bad practice and also generates warnings: `The static method Draw() from the type Triangle should be accessed in a static way`

Comment: Which is why I provided two options, one for removing the static modifier and instantazing and another for accessing the draw method in static context